# Is there a way to disconnect USB device from ADB?

Tags: android, adb

I have a lot of scripts that use ADB to debug Android applications via Wi-Fi with emulators. The problem appears when I charge my Android phone via USB from my computer: ADB sees it and sends commands to my phone instead of emulator.
**Is there a way to disconnect ADB from phone that charges via USB?** I know I can send commands to emulators only via `-e` switch, as well as send them to specific device via `-s` switch. However, it is not OK for me, because I have to rewrite a lot of scripts to add more arguments if I want to implement this device selection feature. I don't need workarounds, I just curious does Google *force* ADB to debug any phone connected via USB that has USB debugging enabled in settings, or it is possible to remove specific USB connected phone from devices list on ADB side?
When I run `adb disconnect`, USB device remains connected.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

USB connection for internal storage and adb connection for debugging are two separate things.

To disable adb - you can use `adb disconnect` or simply turn off `usb debugging` under `developer options`.

For disconnecting usb connection for internal storage certain ROMS have the option. e.g. CM 13 that i have at the moment allows connecting USB just for charging. Generally on other ROMS and Stock ROM I've not seen this option but you can try this. -> If you connect your device via USB while locked the internal storage will not be available unless you unlock the device once.

Comment: As I wrote in my initial post, `adb disconnect` doesn't work. Device is connected back automatically. Try to run `adb disconnect` and `adb devices`, USB will be here.

Comment: in that case you'll need to either turn off the usb debugging from developer options or at least revoke permissions from developer options

Comment: It is solution, however I use my phone for debugging other projects ;) It is time killing to enable or disable debug mode each time I simply want to charge phone. As I wrote in my first post, "I don't need workarounds", actually there are a lot of workarounds, but I don't understand why Google implemented ADB is so strange way that it can not disconnect specific device without its reconfiguration.

Comment: as far as i know nothing exists like that can be used off the shelf for what you want. You are a developer! write a small app/service which responds to usb plugged in event and does what you want. Cant be that hard

Comment: adb disconnect works for me on macOS

Answer (score 12):

ADB doesn't support disconnecting a USB connection now(version 1.0.39).

"adb disconnect" can only disconnect a TCP connection set up by "adb connect", it can not disconnect a USB connection.

You can "disconnect" a connection by using push and reconnect commands as a workaround:

1.push a file to phone

```
adb -s SERIAL push somefile /data/local/tmp
```

2.reconnect while push is still in progress

```
adb -s SERIAL reconnect
```

SERIAL means serial number listed in the output of 'adb devices' command.

Repeat step 1 and 2, after a while, you can find this device is in offline state from output of "adb devices".

No adb command can operate this offline device until you kill-server and start-server.

Comment: What the heck is [serial]? We'd better look up the official documentation which explains those things.

Comment: Romaio, sorry for the mistake, [serial] means serial number, just changed it to SERIAL.

Answer (score 10):

just use ***adb kill-server*** to kill the connection
***adb disconnect*** also works

Answer (score 0):

On the device itself go to Developer options. There is a "USB debugging" switch. You can simply switch off "USB debugging" while you don't need the device to be seen by adb. 
Alternatively (if, say, you want "Trust this device?" window appear on the device again) you can tap "Revoke USB debugging authorizations" option (also in Developer options. Tapping it will revoke all authorizations, including the one for your PC. Doing that will also restrict access from adb. To re-enable adb connection for the device, disable and re-enable the "USB debugging" switch. That will force "Trust this device?" window appear on the mobile device (should be unlocked for that perpose). Say "ok" and you should be able to connect via adb again.

Answer (score -1):

Update your scripts to use the the id of the emulator so that you can direct adb commands to emulator:

```
adb -s{serial_number}
```

Ex:

```
adb -s emulator-5556 install myApp.apk
```

If you have only one emulator you can also use '-e' to direct adb commands to emulator.

```
adb -e install myApp.apk
```

The same can be done to force commands to your mobile, using '-d'.